# JSP displays null values despite having data

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets

I have this data passed to JSP from servlet:

```
[
    Document {
        {_id=59d25b1e41affc3dbc3b47c4, name=John, address=Baker Street}
    }, 
    Document {
        {_id=59d2a67541affc33ccc98a0b, name=John, address=Baker Street}
    }
]
```

The JSP file.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${NameList}" var="document">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${document.string('name')}" escapeXml="true" /></td>   
            <td><c:out value="${document.string('address')}" escapeXml="true" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach> 
</table>
```

But, I am not getting any value displayed in my JSP.

Could someone help me figure out the mistake that I am doing?

EDIT:

This is my query which searches for the fields in MOngoDb using the keyword:

```
    List<Document> NameList= collection.find(eq("name", fname)).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

the Document is from org.bson.Document

I sent this to JSP using the following code:

```
     request.setAttribute("NameList", NameList);
     request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Then in the main.jsp, I have the code that is given before this edit section.

Since I am new to both JSP, servlet and MongoDB I do not understand how I can extract the exact data like name, address from the list that I pass.

Comment: Not enough code. Show where "NameList" and "document" are set

Comment: @Jonathan Laliberte I have edited the section with more code. Could you have a look at it and lead me ahead to get the desired results on JSP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: still not enough code. if you have set those variables, then you can call them like this:

Comment: <td><c:out value="${document.name}" escapeXml="true" /></td>

Comment: @Jonathan Laliberte I am afraid that did not work either since I remember trying it and tried yet again. Data isn't displayed although it is passed on to JSP successfully.
Is there something wrong with the code I pasted in the question?

Comment: there's not enough of it to understand your problem..What do you see if you do just:
<c:out value="${NameList}" />

Comment: @ Jonathan Laliberte It won't display anything. Actually when I try displaying it outside of the <c:for each.. loop it displays
[
    Document {
        {_id=59d25b1e41affc3dbc3b47c4, name=John, address=Baker Street}
    }, 
    Document {
        {_id=59d2a67541affc33ccc98a0b, name=John, address=Baker Street}
    }
]

Comment: @Jonathan Laliberte I would want to mark your answer as correct. This worked Problem was there was no jstl jar included. Thanks a lot for the help. Please write the answer instead of comments so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem in the end, that's an honest mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there doesnt seem to be anything wrong with the code, try narrow down the problem by doing just this outside the loop:

```
<c:out value="${NameList}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!